# Showing data from category with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, categories

My tables are:

1. barangtbl: id, judul_barang, judul_seo, keywords, deskripsi, id_kat, id_sub, id_supersub, kategori_seo, view, gambar
2. kategori: id_kat, nama_kat
3. subkategori: id_sub, id_kat, nama_sub
4. supersubkategori: id_supersub, id_sub, id_kat, nama_supersub

I have a problem with showing data in category from database with PHP, the problem is when i click link: localhost/test/category.php?name=HPI, it doesn't show any data, but if I change HPI with number: 15, it show all.

15 is id_supersub data on supersubkategori table where I join with barangtbl table. So, all i want is if someone click: localhost/test/category.php?name=HPI it will show data with HPI category inside. How solve this problem?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name']))
{
    $kategori = $_GET['name']; 
}

include "config.php";

if ((isset($kategori)) =='')
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM barangtbl INNER JOIN supersubkategori on supersubkategori.id_supersub = barangtbl.id_supersub ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,12";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($hasil);
}
else
{
    echo "
                <table width=\"100%\">
                    <tr>
                        <td align=\"center\"><b><font color=\"red\" size=\"2.5\">[ ".$_GET['name']." ]</b></font></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM barangtbl WHERE id_supersub = '$kategori' ORDER BY id";
    $hasil = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($hasil);
}
?>

<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="2" align="center">
    <tr>
    <?php
        $kolom=3;
        $x = 0;
        if($numrows > 0)
        {
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
            {
                if ($x >= $kolom) 
                {
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                    $x = 0;
                }
        $x++;
    ?>
        <th>             
            <div id="title">
                <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $data['judul_barang']; ?>
                </a>
            <br><br>
          </div>

          <div id="image">
            <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
                <img width='150' height='150' valign='top' border='1,5' src="product/<?php echo $data['gambar']; ?>" />
            </a>
            <br><br>
            </div>       

        <div id="action">
        <?php 
            echo '
                    <a href="product.php?id='.$data['id'].'">
                        <img src="images/detail.jpg"\ title="Detail Barang" border="0" width=\"50\" height=\"30\">
                    </a>';
                ?>
            </div>
          <hr />    
        </th>
    <?php
        }
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does your **id_supersub** contain and what data type is it ?

Comment: id_supersub contain same/related id/ number from supersubkategori table and the data type is int @RohitGupta

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM barangtbl WHERE id_supersub = $kategori ORDER BY id";
```